# choose info.plist file

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, cocoa-touch

I have localized my Info.plist file, because I have to have different names for the app in different languages.

Since I did that, the project window shows this button: choose info.plist file.

[image]

If I click this button a window pops up with no choices. And worst than that, the project will not compile, giving an error **error: could not read data from '/Users/user/Documents/myApp/Info.plist': The file “Info.plist” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file.**

In fact the message is correct, because Xcode removed it from that location and added a copy of Info.plist to every localized directory (en.lproj, PT.lproj, etc.).

So... how do I fix this?

Comment: you have to create a generic `Info.plist` file, you can clone any existing `Info.plist` file, and then you have to add to your project. the same issue happens if you create different targets, no matter you don't have such a target, you must have a default `Info.plist` file with the same name as you had for the first target.

Comment: what do you mean? Info.plist was there. I clicked "localize this file" . Xcode moved the file to en.lproj, pt.lproj, etc., and Xcode removed the file from the project root. This is how it works with all files that are localized.

Comment: yep, try to put a default `Info.plist` file _outside_ of the `.lproj` folders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After fighting with Xcode, the only solution that works is this: http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/12/15/localize-iphone-application-name.html

You cannot localize Info.plist as I did. you have to create a strings file and localize that. Some magic links the the strings file to the info.plist.